# MySQL connection error

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

When I am trying to use SQLyog to connect to my MySQL database, it is giving the error like

> Error No. 2005
>   Unknown MySQL server host 'database.ch3.s.com' (11004)

Any idea what can be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried pinging the hostname, go to the command prompt and type 'ping database.ch3.s.com'

I have found scenarios where the database hostname is not available to external connections (ping will fail) but it works on the server.  In this case you simply can't create an external connection to the database and will have to use the servers phpMyAdmin or equivalent.

Comment: tried pinging but it gives "Ping request could not find host dbdddd.stress.ch3.s.com. Please check the name a
nd try again."

Comment: It is possible to kill-ping requests for security reasons. When you do this it is harder to indentify if a ip-address is active.

Comment: My pc was not in that VLAN. Now its in it and able to connect :)

Answer (score 0):

Databse server may be down or there might be a proxy server which can prevent you to access the DB server.

Comment: Good thinking. Also may remote access being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The address of the MySQL databases seems to be invalid. The address 'database.ch3.s.com', is this a subsitute or is this the real address you are using?